# Office 365 API Calendar webLink display

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-web-app

Have currently implemented some client side code to retrieve items from my calendar.  This works as expected and I get the items returned with a WebLink property.  What i was expecting was that when I navigate to this WebLink address that I would get the OWA view of that item.

However when I navigate to the link I get this view rather than the view I get navigating through OWA.

[WebLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PndZe.png)

[OWA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lswfd.png)

Does anyone know how I can modify the WebLink to get the OWA view instead?

Answer (score 1):

The web link is the read view for the calendar item. If you want the Office 365 REST to support the link for the edit view, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).